# I'm receiving a 400 bad request error: "A non-empty request body is required" from my fetch request, despite my fetch request having a body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api

Everytime I make a fetch request from my frontend using the following js code I receive a 400 Bad request status. The body of the response has an error object saying: "A non-empty request body is required".

When I inspect the request section on my devtools network tab it says "no payload for this request". So it looks to me it's not sending the body section of my Fetch.

It does reach the `.then()` method afterwards.

This is the Typescript Code:

```
fetch(`api/person/${person.id}`, {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(person)
})
  .then(() => this.router.navigate(["/"]))
```

this is the C# backend:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, Person person)
{
    person.Id = id;

    try
    {
       var updatedPerson = _personRepository.Update(person);
       if (updatedPerson != null)
       {
            return Ok(updatedPerson);
       }

       return NotFound();
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Note that the request doesn't even reach this controller. No break points will be reached if I place any here.

This is a single page application I run from Visual Studio 2019.

It works with postman however, returning the 200 Ok status code and an object back, and reaching backend breakpoints. The request URL contains the `int id` and the body containing a Json object.

Comment: The reason why controller is not reached is probably there is middleware to validate the request body. Does your browser send another request like `Options` or `Fetch` together with your request to the same url? It smells like something is wrong with headers to allow body. Refer to CORS policy

Comment: @AbrorAbdullaev according to the Network tab it only sends PUT. I don't think anything else is being sent. Please could you expand on what I could do with CORS policy? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that  javascript person is not null? Did you check developer tools of the browser for javascript error?

Comment: @Serge Yes I have checked that and the person object is indeed present. I have more details about what happened in the replies under the other answer. I have now come to find out that doing the request with Angular's httpClient doesn't error, however the fetch function does.

Comment: @alalalal  Did you check the Console of  developer tools of browser? it usually shows javascript errors

Comment: @Serge Yes I have checked the Dev tools. The console and Network tabs say the same thing that it was a bad request and a code of 400. There aren't any errors beyond that other than some errors about connecting to sockjs/websocket. I think backend is fine as it works with postman and httpClient.

Comment: @alalalal Did you try to put "/" to url. I am usually using "/api/person/${person.id}"

Comment: @Serge I've just tried that now and it doesn't seem to solve it. Same error as before.

Comment: But how do you call the API  do you have javascript  on the click? usually API  has a different url then the applicaton and you neeed the full url "http://localhost..."

Comment: Yes there is a submit button that sends the request. When I view the URL on the Network tab the url is correct as well but I still get a 400 error. The difference in the front/backend url is "/api/" that comes after port. So "localhost:5001/api/", and frontend: "localhost:5001/". This is an issue with the JavaScript's Fetch function as doing the same request using Angular's httpClient instead of this fetch works fine.

Comment: You can't submit fetch code directly. YOu should use onbutton click javascript code.  It would be nice to see how you create person object in java.

Comment: Check if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78227963/why-getting-error-whenever-i-request-although-i-am-getting-username-correctly-a Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is not a question that has a clear answer.
Here are steps you could need to take to find out:

- Make sure in your fetch request the argument person is really exist, just do console.log(person) before fetch
- Make sure server accepts 'application/json' type content. Though in this case the response code should have been different.
- Check the response headers, and are the origins of back end and front end are the same? What you need to see are the following:

  ```
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  ```

Postman works as a native app on your PC and has different way of sending requests rather than your browser, sometimes this causes unclear results.

Comment: I've checked the argument and the person object does indeed exist. Your third point is most important, I don't have those 3 lines in my response header. Frontend and backend both run on https://localhost:5001. I'm not too sure how to check if the server accepts 'application/json' type content but I assume it does according the response code.

Comment: Now try to find out if the body is not being attached by your browser or being lost on the way to server?
 - Try to use some other library like axios to send the same request, maybe fetch is causing issue.

Comment: I have tried it with Angular's HttpClient and the request works now. Which is strange. The issue has something to do with the Fetch function.

Comment: @alalal I had similar issue and in my case it was because I didn't attach the authorization headers to the request. But if that would be your case you would get different error. Still show your headers, request and response maybe it will say something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to test what is happening.

1. Go to your main web site (http://localhost:5001 or whatever) in your
   browser
2. Open up Browser Dev Tools (F12 in most browsers)
3. copy / paste the following fetch (code below) into your Dev console
   & press

What happens?  Do you get data back (printed in console)?
This will probably get you to the next step you need to take.

```
fetch("api/person/1")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: That is a get request. It's just the "Put" request causing these issues. I've just pasted that code in the console and it does work.